# Should URI's be redirected to subdomains?

Tags: symfony, routes, seo, subdomain, rdf

I am trying to figure out my routes in Symfony2 to make them RDF-friendly. I have a site where there are distinct subdomains such as:

**EDIT:** each `topic` is stored in a separate bundle

- `topic1.domain.com`
- `topic2.domain.com`

To be RDF-friendly (as I understand it), these topics would need to be defined in this way:

`www.domain.com/topic1/products/#`

...rather than...

`topic1.domain.com/products/#`

If this is the case, should I permanently redirect the following?

`www.domain.com/topic1 --> topic1.domain.com`

...or would this mess up SEO? (ie permanently redirecting `domain.com --> www.domain.com`)

Comment: *"To be RDF-friendly (as I understand it), these topics would need to be defined in this way ..."* I don't understand this part of the question. RDF just uses URIs as opaque identifiers for things.  `http://topic1.domain.com/products/#42` is just as good a URI as `http://www.domain.com/products/#42`.  If there's supposed to be a global list of topics, it might be nice for *humans* to see the all with a common prefix, but any tool processing RDF qua RDF doesn't care.  Does Symfony2 do some deeper processing on the URIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding SEO, it does not matter if you redirect or not, as long as the content is returned properly and you always use the same URL for the same content (well it is not an obligation for the latter, but it is more SEO efficient - learn about canonical URLs for more details).